# Task-list app, which allows to add and remove tasks from list

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, sass

I wrote my first web app. Please let me know what I should improve. I want to write as clean code as possible.

App is about adding and removing tasks from list. Backend is written in Django, frontend in Sass and JavaScript.

Below my code for items view. Whole project can be seen in link:

[Link to my code on GitHub](https://github.com/Damiant94/TodoList)

Demo:

[Link to app on heroku](http://awesome-todo-list.herokuapp.com/)

Code for items view:

1. JavaScript
2. Sass
3. HTML

```js
// Start with first item
let counter = 0;

// Load 6 items at a time
const QUANTITY_START = 6; 
const QUANTITY_TO_ADD_ON_SCROLL = 3; 

let isListEmpty = true;
let removed = [];
let areMoreItems = true;

const HIDE_ANIMATION_DURATION_OPACITY = 1500

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  // SETTING LISTENERS:
  window.onscroll = () => {
    if (areMoreItems && isScrolledToBottom()){
      const scroll = window.onscroll;
      window.onscroll = "none";
      load(QUANTITY_TO_ADD_ON_SCROLL);
      setTimeout(() => {
        window.onscroll = scroll;
      }, 1000);
    } 
  }

  deleteItemListener();
  confirmDeleteButtonListener();
  // END OF SETTING LISTENERS

  load(QUANTITY_START);
})

function confirmDeleteButtonListener() {
  const confirm_button = document.querySelector(".confirm-delete-button");
  confirm_button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    confirm_button.value = removed.join();
  })
}

function deleteItemListener() {
  document.querySelector(".main").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if(event.target.nodeName === "I") {

      const itemElement = event.target.parentElement.parentElement;
      const item_id = itemElement.querySelector('.id').innerHTML;
      removed.push(item_id);

      itemElement.style.animationPlayState = 'running';
      // itemElement.addEventList;

      document.querySelector(".confirm-delete-button").disabled = false;
    }
  });
}

function isScrolledToBottom() {
  return window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.body.offsetHeight
}

function load(quantity) {

  const start = counter;
  const end = start + quantity - 1;
  counter = end + 1;

  fetch(`itemslist?start=${start}&end=${end}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    if (data.itemslist.length > 0) {
      isListEmpty = false;
      data.itemslist.forEach(addItem);
    } else {
      areMoreItems = false;
      if (isListEmpty) {
        addEmptyListInfo();
      }
    }
  });
}

function addEmptyListInfo() {
  const item = document.createElement('section');
  item.className = "empty-list";
  item.innerText = "Your list is empty";
  document.querySelector('.main-items').append(item)
}

function addItem(item) {
  const itemNode = document.createElement('section');
  itemNode.className = "todo-item";
  itemNode.innerHTML =     
    `<p hidden class="id">${item.id}</p>
    <div name="delete-button" value="${item.id}" class="x-wrapper">
      <i class="far fa-times-circle"></i>
    </div>
    <h2 name="name" class="todo-item-name">${item.name}</h2>
    <label for="details">Details:</label>
    <p class="details" name="details">${item.details}</p>
    <p class="date">Deadline: ${item.date}</p>`;
  document.querySelector('.main-items').append(itemNode);
};
```

```css
.nav {
  .li {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Caveat', cursive;
    color: #fff;
    outline: none;
  }

  form {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}

.main-items {
  opacity: 0.9;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row !important;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  .todo-item {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    color: #000;
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0 15px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: hide;
            animation-name: hide;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
            animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
            animation-play-state: paused;
    background-image: url(../img/sticky1.png);
    background-size: 400px 300px;
    line-height: 100%;

    .todo-item-name {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
         -ms-flex-pack: center;
       justify-content: flex-start;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
         -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      margin-left: 40px;
      margin-right: 25px;
      height: 40px;
      font-size: 25px;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin-top: 20px;
      padding: 5px;
      outline: none;
      color: #000;
      overflow-y: auto;
      scrollbar-width: thin;
      scroll-padding: 0;
      scroll-margin: 0;
      white-space: nowrap;
      cursor: default;
    }

    .details {
      border-radius: 5px;
      overflow-wrap: break-word;
      overflow-y: auto;
      height: 100px;
      padding: 10px;
      margin-left: 40px;
      margin-right: 25px;
      text-align: justify;
      resize: none;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      outline: none;
      font-size: 22px;
      scrollbar-width: thin;
      scroll-padding: 0;
      scroll-margin: 0;
      cursor: default;
      }

    .x-wrapper {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      margin: 10px;
      font-size: 20px;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
      transition: all 0.2s;
      cursor: pointer;
      border: none;
      color: #e9c1c1;
      background-color: transparent;
    }

    .x-wrapper:hover {
      color: #fff;
    }
  }

  .empty-list {
    font-size: 44px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 10px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  .todo-item label {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 25px;
  }

  .date {
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 25px;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes hide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes hide {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
{% extends "TodoListApp/base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block style %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'TodoListApp/css/items.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'TodoListApp/css/loader.css' %}">
  <title>Items</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
  <div id="loader-wrapper">
    <div id="loader"></div>
    <div class="section-left"></div>
    <div class="section-right"></div>
  </div>

  <nav class="nav">
    <a href="{% url 'newitem' %}">
      <div class="li">Add new item</div>
    </a>
    <form action="{% url 'items' %}" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <button class="add-10-items li" value="add-10-items" name="add-10-items">add 10 items</button>
      <button disabled class="confirm-delete-button li" value="" name="confirm-delete-button">confirm deleting</button>
    </form>
    <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">
      <div class="li">Logout</div>
    </a>
  </nav>

  <div class="container container-items">
    <header class="header">
      <h1>Hello :{{ name }}:</h1>
      <h1>Here is a list of your activities:</h1>
    </header>
    <main class="main main-items">

    </main>
  </div>

  <script src="{% static 'TodoListApp/js/items.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'TodoListApp/js/loader.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Adding elements

As pointed out in "CertainPerformance's" answer adding content via HTML in this case can present a security risk.

However adding elements via innerHTML should always be avoided as it is very inefficient, noisy, and hard to read and maintain (due to there being no code formatting in a string)

With a few simple functions you can avoid the very slow setter `.innerHTML` and add content in an efficient way, without the verbosity of the DOM API.

The following set of functions can take care of most of your HTML creation needs

- `tag` creates an element and adds properties, returning the new tag.
- `append` appends siblings to an element, returning the parent.
- `query` queries an element returning the found element (if found)

Code

```
const tag = (tag, props = {}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props);
const append = (par, ...sibs) => sibs.reduce((p, sib) => (p.appendChild(sib), p), par);
const query = (qStr, el = document) => el.querySelector(qStr);
```

And would replace your code with

```
function load(quantity) {
    const url = `itemslist?start=${counter}&end=${counter + quantity - 1}`;
    const mainItems = query(".main-items");
    counter = end + 1;

    fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data.itemslist.length > 0) {
                isListEmpty = false;
                append(mainItems, ...data.itemslist.map(addItem));
            } else {
                areMoreItems = false;
                isListEmpty && append(mainItems, addEmptyListInfo());
            }
        });
}

function addEmptyListInfo() {
  return tag("section", {className: "empty-list", textContent: "Your list is empty"});
}
function addItem(item) {
    return append(tag("section", {className: "todo-item"}),
        tag("p",     {hidden: true, className: "id", textContent: item.id}),
        append(tag("div", {name: "delete-button", value: item.id, className:"x-wrapper"}), 
            tag("i", {className: "far fa-times-circle"})
        ),
        tag("h2",    {name: "name", className: "todo-item-name", textContent: item.name}),
        tag("label", {for: "details", textContent: "Details:"}),
        tag("p",     {className: "details", name:"details", textContent: item.details}),
        tag("p",     {className: "date", textContent: `Deadline: ${item.date}`}),
    );
}
```

### Make the code work for YOU!

Personally I use a modification combing `tag` and `query` and naming it `$` (as I never use jQuery) and name `append` `$$` with helper functions to simplify common properties. Example `$.text`, `$.classText`, `$.class`, create properties, `textContent`, `className` and `textContent`, and `className` plus any additional properties.

There are dozens of ways you can simplify adding content to the page. And the best thing it is lightning fast, you can really notice the speed increase when building a page using the DOM API calls

```
function addItem(item) {
    return $$( $("<section>", $.class("todo-item")),
        $("<p>", $.classText("id", item.id, {hidden: true})),
        $$( $("<div>", $.class("x-wrapper", {name: "delete-button", value: item.id}), 
            $("<i>", $.class("far fa-times-circle"))
        ),
        $("<h2>", $.classText("todo-item-name", item.name, {name: "name"})),
        $("<label>", $.text("Details:", {for: "details"})),
        $("<p>", $.classText("details", item.details, {name:"details"})),
        $("<p>", $.classText("date", `Deadline: ${item.date}`))
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty good code, I'd remove variable `isListEmpty` as it does nothing at all, your if else branch already checks for empty list and you get rid of one ugly global variable.

Consider getting rid of all the global variables by wrapping functions, that need them into either into class or another function. that way variables are not global, and you can even pass some of these as parameters (ex: `QUANTITY_START`).

`addEmptyListInfo` and `addItem` have identical first and last line. You can extract middle of them into separate functions and create 3rd common function to avoid redundancy and make sure adding new "section" is only in one place.

I don't like that `fetch` url is hardcoded into .js file. Consider extracting it somewhere into html as data-attribute, that way you can control how is url generated and if you change django routing, you don't have to modify url in multiple places.

Consider extracting debounce listener of scroll into separate function, example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12009497/4070660

As for scss, you can use autoprefixer to handle vendor prefixes for you and clean up your code a bit.

Most of time it's better to use other units than pixels. Consider using em/rem or vw/vh/

Nothing comes to mind when checking your html :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Use `const` when possible** - using `let` is a warning to readers of the code that a variable may get reassigned in the future. If that's not actually the case, [better to use `const`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278652/how-much-should-i-be-using-let-vs-const-in-es6) for the `removed` variable; consider [a linter](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-const).

**`removed` array?** Its purpose isn't entirely clear at first glance, I had to read over a few sections of the code to understand what it's doing. Consider naming it `itemIdsToBeRemoved`. Also, `counter` might be better named `lastItemIdLoaded` or something of the sort.

**Use `camelCase` for plain variables**, as is the overwhelming convention in JS: eg, consider using `itemId` and `confirmButton`. (The all-caps numeric constants at the top are just fine.)

**DOMContentLoaded section** You do 4 things there:

- Add a scroll listener
- Call  `deleteItemListener`, `confirmDeleteButtonListener`, and `load`

To be stylistically consistent, consider abstracting the scroll listener into a separate function, like you're doing with the other listeners. (But the functions aren't *event listeners themselves* - they *add* event listeners, so maybe call them, eg, `addDeleteConfirmListener`)

**Load quantity complication** Juggling a dynamic number of items requested from the server seems a bit overcomplicated for my tastes. Unless you're expecting to have huge payloads, I think it'd make a bit more sense to fetch *all* items immediately, and then sort through what should be displayed at what time *on the client*. Sending all items at once will also reduce the visible delay for the user.

If you were to send all items immediately, consider interpolating the data into the HTML, rather than using a request after the page loads. Eg, you could have

```
<script type="application/json" class="items-data">
{"itemslist": [{"id": 191, "user_id": 26, "name": "name", "details": "details", "date": "2020-12-09"}]}
</script>
```

```
const items = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('.items-data').textContent);
```

This will make the page load more quickly for the user; assuming the app's been loaded before and you have a sensible cache policy, they won't have to wait for *two* round-trips to your server for the todos to be displayed, but only one.

**Return early to avoid indentation hell** This:

```
function deleteItemListener() {
  document.querySelector(".main").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if(event.target.nodeName === "I") {
      // big block of code
```

can be

```
function deleteItemListener() {
  document.querySelector(".main").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (event.target.nodeName !== "I") {
      return;
    }
    // big block of code
```

or even

```
function deleteItemListener() {
  document.querySelector(".main").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (event.target.nodeName === "I") {
      deleteItem(event.target);
    }
```

**nodeName?** It's not clear at a glance that a `nodeName` of `i` corresponds to the X icon. Consider giving the `i` a class that indicates what it is, eg `delete-icon`, allowing you to do `e.target.matches('.delete-icon')`.

**Use `.closest`** when navigating to parents - the selector passed to `.closest` can be more informative as to which parent you're navigating to, *and* it's shorter than using `.parentElement.parentElement`:

```
const itemElement = event.target.closest('section');
```

**`innerHTML`, `textContent`, and `innerText`**

- Avoid `innerText`. It's [almost never what you want](http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/) - it has some confusing behaviors. Except in the very few cases where you need to retrieve text using `innerText`'s peculiar formatting quirks, better to use `.textContent` or `.innerHTML`.
- Only use `.innerHTML` when setting or retrieving HTML markup. If all you want to set or retrieve is *plain text*, use `.textContent` instead; `.textContent` is faster, safer, and more semantically appropriate.

Related to the above:

**`innerHTML` is a security risk with user input** I can get your site to execute arbitrary code by entering the following description into a todo:

```
<img src onerror="alert('evil')">
```

I could disguise the markup in other text, then tell another user "Hey, try making a new todo with this description, you won't believe what happens next!" - and then steal their login credentials if they fall for it.

The problem is that you're using:

```
  itemNode.innerHTML =     
    `<p hidden class="id">${item.id}</p>
    ...
    <p class="details" name="details">${item.details}</p>
```

Direct concatentation of an HTML string like that should always be looked at suspiciously. If the interpolated value isn't 100% trustworthy, you probably have problems. To fix it, populate the untrustworthy values into the DOM by setting `.textContent` after creating the element, like this:

```
itemNode.innerHTML = `
  <p hidden class="id">${item.id}</p>
  <div name="delete-button" value="${item.id}" class="x-wrapper">
    <i class="far fa-times-circle"></i>
  </div>
  <h2 name="name" class="todo-item-name"></h2>
  <label for="details">Details:</label>
  <p class="details" name="details"></p>
  <p class="date">Deadline: ${item.date}</p>
`;
itemNode.querySelector('h2').textContent = item.name;
itemNode.querySelector('.details').textContent = item.details;
```

That's if the `id` and `date` are saved in a safe form in your database by your backend, which I'd expect they are, though the code isn't in the question - eg the `id` should be saved as a number, and the date should be saved as a unix timestamp or a Date. If they aren't and you can't for whatever reason, then you'll need to sanitize whatever comes from the user manually before saving it. If you can't do that either for some reason, then you'll have to insert the `id` and `date` properties into the DOM above by using DOM methods instead of by HTML concatenation - but it'd be better to be sure that they're in an expected, safe format ahead of time.

You could also enable direct concatenation of the `name` and `details` by sending them through a sanitizer before saving them to the database.

Comment: ?? Your security fix `itemNode.innerHTML = ` (last snippet) is incomplete as un-vetted content `item.id` and `item.date` are still being added to the page as markup

Comment: I was assuming that those were saved by the backend in a sensible (and therefore trustworthy) format, but the code that does that isn't in the question, so I guess it's not an entirely safe assumption